# My gitlab-ci-multi-runner doesn't recognize npm command

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-multi-runner and spin this one up with docker compose.

The weird thing is that my jobs get stuck on npm command not recognized.
But my base image is node:latest, so it should work.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
   - node_modules/

before_script:
   - npm install
   - bower install --allow-root

stages:
   - build_deploy

build_&_deploy_app:
  stage: build_deploy
  only:
   - master
script:
   - gulp build -production
   - gulp deploy

variables:
   GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"
```

Note: I needed to turn of SSL verification, because that is another issue to fix.

The output of the job is:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.1.4 (9e2fd1a)
WARNING: image is not supported by selected executor and shell
Using Shell executor...
Running on 6687502ce71f...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 42e9d51 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
Checking out 42e9d511 as master...
HEAD is now at 42e9d51... Update .gitlab-ci.yml
Checking cache for default...
$ npm prune
bash: line 56: npm: command not found

ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: What is your runner configuration? It seems that you just configured it as a shell runner, not docker.

Comment: I was running it as RUNNER_EXECUTOR=shell, I changed it to docker but it gives me the same error.

Comment: I updated the job output. It looks if it always runs the runner as shell executor.

Comment: So you have to configure it to use the docker runners
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-in-config-toml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and registering my runner as docker executor helped:
first I unregistered all my runners with **sudo gitlab-runner unregister --all-runners** and then I registered a runner with docker executor:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register \
--non-interactive \
--url "https://gitlab.com/" \
--registration-token "<Your registration token>" \
--executor "docker" \
--docker-image alpine:latest \
--description "docker-runner" \
--tag-list "docker,aws" \
--run-untagged="true" \
--locked="false" \
--access-level="not_protected"
```